# CQRS applying command handler business logic

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am applying sample CQSR to an application. And I am confused about applying logical rules.

```cs
public class UserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUserCommand>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository repository;

    public UserCommandHandler(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateUserCommand command)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Username = command.Username;
        user.Password = command.Password;
        user.Email = command.Email;
        user.CreteDate = DateTime.Now;
        // Rules
        var isUserDuplicated = repository.GetAll().Any(u => u.Username == command.Username);
        var isEmailDuplicated = repository.GetAll().Any(u => u.Email == command.Email);

        repository.Add(user);
        repository.Save();
    }
}
```

1. Where can I apply business rules to check if username duplicated or email duplicated.
2. My command handler is void. So how can I send duplication notification to users?

Answer (score 2):

Email addresses and usernames being unique are not really a domain concern, so they could be enforced with a simple database constraint or using application handler logic like you have.  The domain model should be reserved for rules that are likely to change and rules that business experts speak of.

The best approach for notifying users of a failure is to not have a failure :)  Commands should very rarely fail, in which case you would throw an exception.  You instead must be proactive and validate input client side.  You could query to see if the username is unique right in your client application or website.  If it is unique, then send the command.